# Grouping by ranges with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, enums, java-stream, grouping

As the title implies, I am trying to is groupingBy to group a list of objects by range of their "power levels". I am very new to Java Stream API, so I don't quite know my way around it. The code I have written won't compile and I'm just not certain why, I think I have the right idea, but it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated! You can find my failed attempt below.

This is the groupingBy attempt:

```java
Map<BigDecimal, List<Employee>> ranges = ObjectList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> {
            if(a.powerLevel < 2500) { a.powerLevel = LOWER;}
            else if(a.powerLevel >10000) {a.powerLevel = UPPER;}
            else {a.PowerLevel = MIDDLE;}
        }
));
```

This is my enum:

```java
enum salaryRanges { 
    LOWER, MIDDLE, UPPER
}
```

PS:I tried to see if I could make an enum with ranges, but from what I've read that it not possible in Java.

Comment: You seem to be trying to modify some object inline. You need a _function_ that returns one of those enum values. Replacing your assignment with `return` may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommended to move logic into different method that defines range

```
   public static salaryRanges getRange(Employee employee) {
    if(employee.powerLevel < 2500){
        return salaryRanges.LOWER;
    }

    if(employee.powerLevel > 10000){
        return salaryRanges.UPPER;
    }

    return salaryRanges.MIDDLE;
}
```

Then use `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
  Map<salaryRanges,List<Employee>> res = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(JavaMain::getRange));
```

You can also do it in another way as @Andreas suggested, by moving defining salary range logic into enum

```
enum salaryRanges {
LOWER, MIDDLE, UPPER

public static salaryRanges fromPowerLevel(int powerLevel){
    if(powerLevel<2500){
        return salaryRanges.LOWER;
    }

    if(powerLevel>10000){
        return salaryRanges.UPPER;
    }

    return salaryRanges.MIDDLE;
  }
}
```

And then calling that method using lambda expression

```
 Map<salaryRanges,List<Employee>> res = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(emp->salaryRanges.fromPowerLevel(emp.powerLevel)));
```

Comment: I would recommend changing the method signature to `fromPowerLevel(int powerLevel)` instead, and move the method to the `salaryRanges` enum class, making it reuable and decoupled from `Employee`. It would then be used as `groupingBy(e -> salaryRanges.fromPowerLevel(e.powerLevel))`. --- While at it, I would also rename enum to `SalaryRanges`, to follow standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: Yup always new suggestion and good for me to learn @Andreas

Comment: The result is a `Map<salaryRanges, List<Employee>>`

Comment: may i know why `int` is preferred ? and if `powerLevel` is `Integer` then it will cause auto unboxing right ?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `powerLevel` is `Integer`? --- Regardless, since it is *used* as an `int` inside the method, let the caller unbox if needed, so that if the caller does have it as an `int`, it won't need to be auto-boxed just to be auto-unboxed again.